# How are Disk Images Written?

Tags: iso-image, img

How are disk images such as iso, img, and dmg written? For example, if I make a file with no extension with some text in it and put it in a disk image, how does it get incorporated, with what kind of parameters?

Comment: I am not seeing how your second question relates to the first. You will simply have a file, in the ISO archive, with no extension. You should work on refining the first question and discard the second.

Comment: One bit at a time...;->

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, an ISO file is composed of uncompressed files merged into a single file, with various attributes identifying the type of file system and potentially the physical medium.